# Create Database with ready Data

Tags: android, file, save, android-file, rsqlite

I want store my Images in Database. I know How create this database, but How I can insert Images in it?
I wanted save them in Resources and then add in database, but then I can;t delete them.
I want hold Images in android app, insert them in database and delete from holded place. How I can do it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting your 'image bitmap' to 'byte array string',

```
  Bitmap bitmap = YOUR_BITMAP;
  ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
  byte[] byteArray = outStream.toByteArray();
  String imageString=new String(byteArray);
```

You can save this imageString to DB.

While retrieving you can do the following,

```
  byte[] byteArray = imageString.getBytes();
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: From where i can get this bitmap. If from Drawable resources, than i can;t delete them after adding in database, becouse Resource is only readable.

Comment: Yes. You can get it from url or camera.

Comment: can I put needed images in some folder of my app manually, than add them in Database and delete from folder?

Comment: You cannot put inside app. You can save those images to external card. Save them to database and delete it.

Comment: If you want images only in database then hardcode them by converting those images to Base64 String and save it in DB[Hardcode]. You can convert those strings to Images by using above code. [Image to Base64](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/image-to-base64/). You can check that result Base64 by converting that to Image. [Base64 to Image](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).